# GLSL: memory exhausted

Tags: opengl-es, three.js, glsl, webgl

I am working on a WebGL scene with ~100 different 2048 x 2048 px textures. I'm rendering points primitives, and each point has a texture index and texture uv offsets that indicate the region of the given texture that should be used on the point.

Initially, I attempted to pass each point's texture index as a `varying` value, then I attempted to pull the given texture from a `sampler2D` array using that index position. However, this yielded an error that one can only fetch `sampler2D` array values with a "constant integer expression", so now I'm using a gnarly if conditional to assign each point's texture index:

```
/**
* The fragment shader's main() function must define `gl_FragColor`,
* which describes the pixel color of each pixel on the screen.
*
* To do so, we can use uniforms passed into the shader and varyings
* passed from the vertex shader.
*
* Attempting to read a varying not generated by the vertex shader will
* throw a warning but won't prevent shader compiling.
**/

// set float precision
precision highp float;

// repeat identifies the size of each image in an atlas
uniform vec2 repeat;

// textures contains an array of textures with length n textures
uniform sampler2D textures[42];

// identify the uv values as a varying attribute
varying vec2 vUv; // blueprint uv coords
varying vec2 vTexOffset; // instance uv offsets
varying float vTexture; // set index of each object's vertex

void main() {
  int textureIndex = int(floor(vTexture));

  vec2 uv = vec2( gl_PointCoord.x, 1.0 - gl_PointCoord.y );

  // The block below is automatically generated
  if (textureIndex == 0) {vec4 color = texture2D(textures[0], uv * repeat + vTexOffset ); }
  else if (textureIndex == 1) { vec4 color = texture2D(textures[1], uv * repeat + vTexOffset );  } 
  else if (textureIndex == 2) { vec4 color = texture2D(textures[2], uv * repeat + vTexOffset );  } 
  else if (textureIndex == 3) { vec4 color = texture2D(textures[3], uv * repeat + vTexOffset );  } 
  [ more lines of the same ... ]
  gl_FragColor = color;

}
```

If the number of textures is small, this works fine. But if the number of textures is large (e.g. 40) this approach throws:

> ERROR: 0:58: '[' : memory exhausted

I've tried reading around on this error but still am not sure what it means. Have I surpassed the max RAM in the GPU? If anyone knows what this error means, and/or what I can do to resolve the problem, I'd be grateful for any tips you can provide.

**More details:**
Total size of all textures to be loaded: 58MB
Browser: recent Chrome
Graphics card: AMD Radeon R9 M370X 2048 MB graphics (stock 2015 OSX card)

Comment: What's the value of `gl.getParameter(gl.MAX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS)`? You can't have more samplers than that. In WebGL2 you can use texture arrays, otherwise you have to stick with atlases. VRAM can also be a problem - one 8 bit rgba 2048 by 2048 texture is 16MB, so you need 1.6GB in total.

Comment: Thanks @riv `gl.getParameter(gl.MAX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS)` returns 16. I think I'll need to split my rendering up into different draw calls...

Comment: To make one part of @riv's excellent remark a bit more explicit: the "total size of all textures to be loaded" you reported considers the size on disk, which is completely irrelevant for your problem. What matters is the size in (GPU) memory. If you really need to display 100 2048x2048 textures, you probably need to look into texture compression.

Comment: @Paul-Jan thanks for your note. Just so I understand, is texture compression meant to help i/o only, or can it also reduce the RAM footprint in the GPU? Do you know of any other techniques for working with huge amounts of texture data?

Comment: @duhaime texture compression does indeed reduce the GPU memory footprint of textures, that is exactly the purpose it was created for. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API/Compressed_texture_formats for a concise introduction.

Comment: @riv can you make your comment an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Alternative solutions depend very much on your specific problem. You are likely not showing 100 * 2048 * 2048 point primitives simultaneously on screen, so at least some of that texture information does not need to be in memory all the time.

Comment: The compressed textures are actually not the most efficient when it comes to transfer (jpg will be smaller/faster) but are much more efficient when used on the GPU. Agree with @Paul-Jan, if you have a 1920x1080 screen, you can't even show one of those textures in its entirety.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a limit on how many samplers a fragment shader can access. It can be obtained via `gl.getParameter(gl.MAX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS)`. It is guaranteed to be at least 8, and is typically 16 or 32.

To circumvent the limit, texture arrays are available in WebGL2, which also allow indexing layers with any variable. In WebGL1 your only option are atlases, but since your textures are already 2048 by 2048, you can't make ghem any bigger.

If you don't want to limit yourself to WebGL2, you would have to split your rendering into multiple draw calls with diffferent textures set.

Also consider that having 100 8-bit RGBA 2048x2048 textures uses up 1.6 gigabytes of VRAM. Texture compression via `WEBGL_compressed_texture_s3tc` can reduce that by 8x or 4x, depending on how much alpha precision you need.